# How to compress DB backup file with sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2005

I backup my database with this query:

```
USE DBName
GO

DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @FileName = 'C:\Backup\SQLDB\DBName_'+ REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),103),'/','') + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),108),':','') + '.Bak'

BACKUP DATABASE DBName
TO DISK = @FileName
WITH FORMAT,
NAME = 'Full Backup of DBName'
GO
```

I execute this query with a batch file and batch file runs by schedule task.

Batch file parameters:

```
sqlcmd -d DBName -S .\SQLEXPRESS -I -U DBUserName -P DBUserPwd  
       -i SQL_FileName_with_Extension -o log.txt
```

It successfully backup my database on daily basic and I got backup file with `DBName_01082014_131210.bak` name. But it's size is too high (around 7GB). Is there any sql query which executes with above query and which can backup and compress my DB at the same time?

Comment: Hi PRdeep, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You tagged both `mysql` and `sql-server`.  Which one is it?

Comment: you have tagged it both as mysql and sql-server, you really need to be specific what you want?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2005 actually :P

Comment: SQL 2005 doesn't offer native backup compression.  You'd need SQL 2008 Enterprise Ed, SQL 2008 R2 Standard Ed, or greater.  For SQL 2005, you'd have to compress the backup after it was created.  For example, with Win-zip or 7-zip.

Comment: Yes, That's what I want. I am able to create .bak file on daily basis. But now if I want to compress the same, I have to do this manually. I want to do this compression automatically via command line at the time of db backup. However I can do this with 7z command line. But the problem is that, each day the backup file created with a different name (with date/time extension).

Comment: There are (well, were) a number of add-in products that allowed "native" compressed database backups in SQL 2005 and earlier, and they may still be available out there. I used SQL LiteSpeed, and never had any problems with it once I got past the learning curve.

Comment: I've written a batch file that does something similar.  However, it uses date parts only for the filename and assumes the compression event will occur on the same day the db was backed up.  Your example uses both date and time in the backup filename, so my script wouldn't be sophisticated enough.  I'll post it, if you're interested.

Comment: Why not keeping it simple and adjusting that batch file to look for *.bak extention? After all, you don't want to keep the .bak files as they are since you only want to zip them. No?

Comment: @WickedFan, I was thinking something similar.  Instead of deleting the backup file after it's compressed, I'd move it somewhere else.  For example, create the *.bak sql backup in FolderA, compress anything in FolderA (to *.zip, *.7z, whatever), then move the *.bak file to FolderB.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a .bat file. Store the database name in a variable, use sqlcmd to backup the database and after the backup is completed compress it using the db file name from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me. I used a third party utility called 'SQLBackupMaster' to backup, compress and schedule database backup. It's free version is also fulfill my requirements. Now I am able to backup and compress database file on daily and weekly basis. It is working properly (backup and compressing DB file) in SQL Server 2005 express edition as well. Thank you all for giving your kind suggestions.